# RavenDB studio "no databases and no file systems" in embedded mode

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I could not find any information about this online after much searching, any help would be appreciated.

I create my EmbeddableDocumentStore and everything seems to be working fine, my application is using the database. However, when I access the management studio using my port number 5050, it states "No databases and no filesystems are available".

RavenDB.Client and RavenDB.Database nuget package versions are 3.0.3800.

```
var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
{
    DataDirectory = "Data",
    UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
};

store.Configuration.Port = 5050;

store.Initialize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing the question I had an idea and tried it. This resolved the issue but I thought I would post this for reference in case someone had a similar problem.

I could not see this in the docs (http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/server/installation/embedded) but in order to access the resource I had to give it a name.

```
var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
{
    DataDirectory = "Data",
    UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true,
    DefaultDatabase = "Default"
};
```

Now it shows up in the RavenDB studio.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an issue, but by default you'll be connected to the  database. You can still get to this database in the Admin Studio.

Go to "Manage My Server", "To system database" then accept the warning message.

Obviously it shouldn't be used like this but useful if you need to recover data accidentally saved here.

Setting the "DefaultDatabase" property as you've done is the correct solution.